# How to get one complete column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, linux, string-representation

I have a script that will fetch `Last_Error` in `mysql slave` in a particular interval of time and write that to a file.

To fetch `Last_Error`, currently I am using below command in the script.

```
mysql -u root -pxxxxxxxxx -e "show slave status\G;" 2>&1 | grep -v "Warning: Using a password" |grep "Last_Error"
```

The challenge I am facing is that `grep "Last_Error"` will only show that particular line and not complete error. For example, one of my `Last_Error` look like below::

```
Last_Error: Error 'TRIGGER command denied to user 'user'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' for table 'table_name'' on query. Default database: 'Db_name'. Query: 'UPDATE 
                    table 
                 SET 
                    user_status=0 
                 WHERE 
                    contractid ='id.000.000''
```

and one another look like ::

```
Last_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry '117583' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'labs'. Query: 'insert into User (a,b,c,d) values ("Other","",now(),"")
```

So basically I can't use `A4` kind of switch with `grep`. Is it possible to get one complete column in `mysql` or any other work around?

Comment: Probably better asked over on the Unix & Linux stack as your problem isn't really database specific but how to process the output using Unix and Linux command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove all newlines and whitespace from the output before grepping, it should work for you.

Use

```
mysql -u root -pxxxxxxxxx -e "show slave status\G;" 2>&1 | tr -d '\n\r \t' | grep -v "Warning: Using a password" | grep "Last_Error"
```

where the `tr` command removes the newline, carriage return, space, and tab characters from the input.